# Scientific-sounding Adjective meaning long duration

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I would like to find a one word adjective that means: long duration

> The astronauts prepared for a __________ space mission.

Ideally it would sound scientific. I do not think "lengthy" has the feeling I want to convey.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Perhaps this can't, but reasonable research should be shown in any case.

Comment: A thesaurus seems like it would be the place to start. What synonyms for 'lengthy" do you find in a thesaurus (like [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lengthy?s=t)), and how well do you think they fit into your sentence?

Comment: I understand that you want a word that conveys a particular literary impression to the sentence, but as a scientist, I cannot let your request for something that sounds “scientific” go by without commenting that the scientific word in this case is ‘long’. This has a precise scientific meaning and can be expressed in scientific units (of length).

Comment: @David That's a good point you bring up, I'll remember this distinction. I suppose next time I might say: academic sounding or scholarly sounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The astronauts prepared for **an extended** space mission."

**[extended](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extended)** adjective ODOL

> **1.1** Lasting longer than is usual or expected; prolonged.
>   ‘The increased durability and additional surface oxidation protection results in a low initial error rate and extended recording life.’
>   ‘He adds that there has been a push for extended shelf life, driven primarily by the flavored milk category.’

See also:
[protracted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protracted)

Comment: I would have thought that extensive would be better than extended. Extensive just means long. As you say, extended means longer than usual or expected. So I have added my own answer.

Comment: @David Usage, Sir, usage!

Comment: Indeed so. Ironically the Chambers dictionary (I do crosswords) on my iPhone lists only four definitions for ‘extended’ as an adjective, the most pertinent of which is… ‘extensive’. (And this is probably not circular, as the ngram in my answer indicates that ‘extended journey’ became current later than ‘extensive journey’.)

Answer (score 0):

“The astronauts prepared for an **extensive** space mission.”

[**extensive**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extensive) adjective ODOL

> 1.1 Large in amount or scale.
>
> ‘an extensive collection of silver’

Note that, unlike *extended* — the accepted answer — *extensive* has no connotations of **extra** scale or size. This is *not* to imply that *extended* is wrong — the adjective is certainly used in this way — but to explain why I suggest *extensive* may be preferable.

@Kevin has suggested that *extensive* is incorrect as it implies thoroughness. This may reflect the usage in phrases such as “extensive investigation”, but is not implicit in the ODOL definition, above, nor in definition 3a of the OED:

> “Extending over or occupying a large surface or space ; having a wide extent, widely extended.”

Neither of the ODOL examples for *extended* or *extensive* refer to the length of a *journey* (a more general equivalent of “space mission”). However a [A Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extended+journey%2C+extensive+journey&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextended%20journey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextensive%20journey%3B%2Cc0) documents this usage, and, incidentally, shows *extensive journey* predating *extended journey*. The reader can find many examples of *extensive journey* there, but the following — from the first results page of an internet search — are provided for illustration:

> [“The lands of the Bible visited and described in an *extensive journey*…”](https://archive.org/details/landsbiblevisit01wilsgoog)
>
> [“It has been an *extensive journey*. A journey from…”](http://www.absoluteworld.com/2013/10/the-beach-samui-an-extensive-journey/)
>
> [“The *Extensive Journey* of an Eccentric Person”](https://prezi.com/2gp8aj0gaog-/the-extensive-journey-of-an-eccentric-person/)

Comment: Extensive is more about the degree of thoroughness than the duration. Something can be quick but extensive or slow but not extensive.

Comment: @Kevin — My examples negate your comment, for which you provide no supporting documentation. I suggest you reverse your uninformed down vote.

Comment: My "documentation" is a lifetime of speaking English.  Even in your examples there's no evidence the authors used "extensive" to indicate the duration rather than breadth of stops along the journey.

Comment: @Kevin — First I acknowledge the courtesy showed to me by explaining your down vote. You were under no obligation to do so. However I have also spent a lifetime speaking English, as have the ladies who clean my office. Our usage of words differs with education, profession, age and the part of the English-speaking world we live in. That is why on SE EL&U one has to support opinions with dictionaries or examples of usage. Having to do this has knocked me of my high horse on several occasions. You may prefer not to use "extensive" in this context, but that does not mean it is wrong if I do so.

Answer (score 0):

The astronauts prepared for a **long-term** space mission. Something that is long-term has continued for a long time or will continue for a long time in the future. Take a look at this article - https://www.indiatoday.in/education-today/gk-current-affairs/story/nasa-research-on-effects-of-long-term-space-missions-on-human-body-1113221-2017-12-21

Comment: elaborate and add citations to your answer please

Comment: long-term - occurring over or relating to a long period of time or  continuing a long time into the future.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/long-term

Comment: good! now edit that into your answer and elaborate ( defend) it.

Answer (score -1):

If you know how long it will take, try a time-specific adjective. For example [year-long](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/year-long), [month-long](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/month-long) or [week-long](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/week-long). Perhaps you could even say *three month-long* if you need something in-between.

[This article on ReasearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268874473_Transcriptional_Evidence_for_the_Role_of_Chronic_Venlafaxine_Treatment_in_Neurotrophic_Signaling_and_Neuroplasticity_Including_also_Glutatmatergic-_and_Insulin-Mediated_Neuronal_Processes) uses *three-week-long* as an adjective.